# How to create a permanent timer？

Tags: python

i use bpy.app.timers.register add timer, but it does not work after open or drop a new blendfile,
can i create a permanent timer?
that's my code:

```
@persistent
def check_storey_info11(context):
    if bpy.context.scene.active_storey != '':
        context.area.spaces.active.region_3d.view_rotation.angle = 0

    return 0.1

class StoreyWidgetGroup(GizmoGroup):
    bl_idname = "VIEW3D_GGT_use_storey"
    bl_label = "Storey Gizmo Group"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_options = {'3D', 'PERSISTENT'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return True
    
    def setup(self, context):
        bpy.app.timers.register(functools.partial(check_storey_info11, context))
```

Comment: You need to use @persistent decorator see https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html#persistent-handler-example

Answer (score 1):

#### Re-register a timer when open a new file

```
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

debug_int = 0
context = None

def timer_fn():
    global debug_int
    context
    print(debug_int)
    debug_int += 1
    return 1.0

bpy.app.timers.register(timer_fn)

@persistent
def run_when_open_new_file(dummy):
    print("new file detected")
    if not bpy.app.timers.is_registered(timer_fn):
        bpy.app.timers.register(timer_fn)

bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(run_when_open_new_file)
```